# first repeated word in a sentence

Tags: c++11

I'm not sure where the bug is. I'm trying to find the first repeated word in a string where the delimiters are a space, tab, comma, colon, semicolon, dash, and period.

Does anyone see what I'm sure is an obvious error?

```
std::string repeat(std::string str) {
  std::set<std::string> seen;

  str.insert(str.end(), ' ');

  std::string tmp;
  for (auto const& s : str) {
    if (s != ' '&&
        s != '\t'&&
        s != '.'&&
        s != ','&&
        s !=':'&&
        s != ';'&&
        s != '-')
      tmp += s;
    else {
      if (seen.find(tmp) != seen.end())
        return tmp;
      else {
        seen.insert(tmp);
        tmp.clear();
      }
    }
  }

  return "no repeats";
}
```

Comment: @KABoissonneault It's failing on an unknown test case.

Comment: @KABoissonneault Code Review is for ***working code only***

Comment: @learning Are you talking about those online code competitions, where your code gets run against a bunch of tests but you don't know which? Isn't there a platform for code reviews there?

Comment: @syb0rg Right, I somehow missed the part where they said "I'm not sure where the bug is". I was looking for a question and assumed they were just asking for a general review. Still, vague question

Comment: @KABoissonneault yes, but the review site is pretty dead. I was hoping someone would see the issue.

Comment: try various inputs until you find one where your program doesn't get the correct output. At first glance it looks ok to me.

Comment: @learning, what review site are you talking about?

Comment: maybe they time it and your solution is not the most performance efficient one. set is logarithmic, try to use an unordered_set instead. 
Or they track memory consumption and you're not allowed to add an extra character to the input string.

Answer (score 0):

The code as you've written here works fine, as per https://ideone.com/sbsUeI

Your problem is elsewhere. Perhaps check the input string in a debugger and see what is being passed.

Test program (from link):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

std::string repeat(std::string str) {
  std::set<std::string> seen;

  str.insert(str.end(), ' ');

  std::string tmp;
  for (auto const& s : str) {
    if (s != ' '&&
        s != '\t'&&
        s != '.'&&
        s != ','&&
        s !=':'&&
        s != ';'&&
        s != '-')
      tmp += s;
    else {
      if (seen.find(tmp) != seen.end())
        return tmp;
      else {
        seen.insert(tmp);
        tmp.clear();
      }
    }
  }

  return "no repeats";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << repeat("cat dog cat man"); // prints "cat"
    return 0;
}
```